# Avoid 3D transform of Child element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a parent DIV which is 3D transformed and a child element which contains a marker image. Marker image is inheriting the property of parent and also getting 3D transformed in the same manner. I want the child div to have no transformation at all.

I tried various transformations on the child to counter the transformation it got from the parent but was not able to do so.

Here is the link to JS Fiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanchitsaxena9450/qx8ozsj4/)

I am using this transformation to get the floor look in 3D

```
transform: rotateX(70deg)rotateZ(-35deg);
```

I need the marker to look without transformation, so that it appears placed straight over the transformed 3D plane. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylyeo/qx8ozsj4/3/)

First, use `transform-style: preserve-3d` to allow the parent's 3D transformations to carry over to the child's:

```
.parent {
    transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(-35deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Now, perform the reverse transformation on the child using the center bottom as the anchor point.

```
.child {
    transform: rotateZ(35deg) rotateX(-70deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

Be sure the dimensions of the image container matches the image's, or the origin will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

For an easier usage I would sugget to use an outer relative positioned div and overlap the 2 inner divs with position absolute.

```css
.cont {
  position:relative;
}
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform: rotateX(70deg)rotateZ(-35deg);
    margin: 70px;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="parent">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
        <img style="width:60px;height:60px;" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/android-icons/512/location-01-512.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay this works perfectly on JS fiddle. Just one thing more, actually the position of marker is coming from DB which is with respect to parent SVG (The 3D plane one), means they are SVG coordinates. But here we are giving marker position with respect to parent div i suppose. Any idea how to convert those SVG coordinates into their parent div positions ?

Comment: Answer by darryleo seems to be working best in your case